# Rails 4: Turbolinks redirect with flash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Lets say I have a standard controller create action:

```
def create
  @object = Object.new(object_params)
  if @object.save
    redirect_to @object, flash: {success: "Created object successfully."}
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Now if I change the redirect to use turbolinks:

```
redirect_to @object, turbolinks: true, flash: {success: "Created object successfully."}
```

the server returns a text/javascript response, and my browser is displaying it as a white page with just this line of text on it:

```
Turbolinks.visit('http:/localhost:3000/objects/1');
```

How do I make it so my browser actually executes that code instead of displaying it as text?

Also, how can I get the flash success message to appear?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors which is causing the browser to actually submit the form instead of turbolinks intercepting the submit event and sending an ajax request? Check the browser console.

Comment: You first request to create the object was in HTML, so you browser expects to receive a HTML response. But you are sending a JS response, which is interpreted as HTML. Either use `<script>` tags to wrap your Turbolinks redirect or do not use Turbolinks for this redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving this using Turbolinks and [materialize toasts](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html) for a great flash UX:

In my controller:

```
format.js {
  flash[:toast] = 'Created record successfully.'
  render :create
}
```

In create.js.erb:

```
Turbolinks.visit("<%= success_path %>");
```

In my _flash.html.erb partial:

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <% if type == "toast" %>
    <script id="toast">
      $(function() {
        Materialize.toast('<%= message %>', 3000);
      });
    </script>
  <% elsif type == "success" %>
    ...
  <% elsif type == "alert" %>
    ... 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question. But I would suggest using unobtrusive JS for this. You'd want to add `remote: true` in your form first.

```
def create
  @object = Object.new(object_params)
  if @object.save
    flash.now.success = 'Created object successfully.'
  else
    flash.now.alert = @object.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  end
  render :js
end
```

Create a file create.js.erb containing only the following:

```
$('#flash').replaceWith("<%= j render partial: 'layouts/flash' %>");
```

- This is what render :js will be rendered back to the browser, thereby executing a script that will replace your flash container (#flash or whatever id you used) with the new flash messages
- Furthermore make sure that you have a partial view file app/layouts/_flash.html.erb which contains your flash HTML code.

### Update:

If not using Unobtrusive JS. You can render the partial file like the following:

```
def create
  @object = Object.new(object_params)
  if @object.save
    flash.now.success = 'Created object successfully.'
  else
    flash.now.alert = @object.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  end
  render partial: 'layouts/flash'
end
```

Then in your HTML, you embed something like the following:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    url : '<%= url_for objects_path %>',
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (response) {
        $('#flash').replaceWith(response);
    }
});
```

P.S. You might also be interested with [Wiselinks](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks) which actually does this already (partial view loading; you specify the target container to be replaced). Because currently `turbolinks` do not have support yet with partial loading, it always loads the whole body.

Comment: Somehow I remember unobtrusive javascript being depreciated? I could be wrong. In any case, our team doesn't use the .js.erb approach...but I believe I could get this working with a jquery live call in the html.

Comment: I am interested to know where you read that  `unobtrusive javascript being deprecated` as last time I checked, it is very much recommended. Yes you can still embed the javascript in the HTML itself  rather than being called remotely (such as this Unobstrusive JS). You will then instead render the partial HTML file. I will try to update the answer.

Comment: You're right I think. It is not. Its just the .js.erb approach that our team moved away from.

Comment: @GregBlass, I updated the code. I am not too confident this is the best solution, but I think it would work :)

Comment: I got this working, but you can't use the `.success` method on `flash.now` anymore. As such I had to use `flash[:success] = "Message"` instead. It works perfectly well without the `now` method. Cheers.